# How to get Bamboo build number in build.gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle, bamboo

I am trying to access the bamboo build number in build.gradle but am unable to access it there. Following are the options I have tried so far inside `build.gradle`:

```
System.getenv ()["bamboo.buildNumber"]
System.getenv ()["bamboo_buildNumber"]

project.hasProperty("bamboo_buildNumber")
project.hasProperty("bamboo_buildNumber")
```

I even tried creating a variable for my build plan with variable name as BUILD_NUMBER and variable value as `${bamboo.buildNumber}` and accessed it using the below methods, but the values are not getting accessed.

```
System.getenv ()["BUILD_NUMBER"]
project.hasProperty("BUILD_NUMBER")
```

Answer (score 5):

I got the variable value using - 
System.getenv ()["bamboo_buildNumber"]

Comment: This one worked for me too. System.getenv('bamboo.buildNumber') is not working.

Answer (score 4):

To access the environment variable from the **build.gradle** script use **System.getenv()** function:

```
System.getenv('bamboo.buildNumber')
```

Note that this variable should be exported before executing the script. But Bamboo does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Uday, I used the following.

```
System.env['bamboo_buildNumber']
```